# Add activity to navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer app in Android.

How can I go to another activity when user selects an option from the menu?

Also how to add different activities based on option click on the menu

Comment: Please [edit] with some code. Surely you have `onNavigationItemSelected`, as almost all NavigationView tutorials show

Comment: Yes but if I call an activity class when onNavigationItemSelected it open activity but navigation drawer will be disappered

Comment: You need to replace another fragment in this case rather than opening a new activity.

Comment: Current activity which is displayed starting of the app is not a fragment it's just an activity how can I replace this activity now which is not fragment

Comment: Fragments are contained *within* Activities. The Activity holds *one NavigationView* and *one layout* to hold Fragments. The items that you click *should replace Fragments*, not start Activities because *you will lose your drawer*

Comment: Ooh thanks I understood I'll try this now

Answer (score 3):

By reading your question and your comments on previous answer, your requirements seem like you want a `Navigation Drawer` in the activity and want user to make selections based upon the choices available in the Drawer menu. So as you told when you fire intent to start new Activity on selection of choice from menu then the Navigation Drawer disappears. This is because Navigation Drawer is a Fragment and any Fragment in Android is a part of Activity so when first Activity is hidden then Navigation Drawer will be hidden. So what we can do is we can have single activity in our application and multiple fragments. Fragment is just a view in your activity you can replace view in your activity on the selection of any choice from the menu of Navigation Drawer. So change contents of the view of your activity by just changing fragments. Have look at this [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer). This is the way better approach than of changing activities, just change fragments not activities. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks on that item get the item id and use the Intent class. Follow the below:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.custom_id:
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
    }
}
```

Similarly you can get the remaining id's and call the same way.

Comment: If I call like this when second activity started then navigation drawer will be disappeared

Comment: You want navigation in the second screen also?. What i understood from you question is, just clicking on the navigation menu item you need to call the another activity isn't correct.